# How much is a "small, meaningless" transaction?

Tags: transactions

[Tezos documentation](https://tezos.gitlab.io/master/whitedoc/proof_of_stake.html) states:

> A small delegate who is afraid they might be deactivated because they were not given the opportunity to create any block or endorsement can ensure they do not become deactivated by making small, meaningless transactions with their security deposits once every two cycles.

I wonder what exactly is a "small, meaningless" transaction. Is it the lowest possible allowed by the wallet/client? Also, what type of transaction is this? Can be both adding and subtracting funds from the deposit?

Answer (score 5):

Any transaction will do, even an amount of 0. Note that you may need to include a small transaction fee to ensure the transaction is relayed by your peers and included inside a block.

Comment: So does that mean it is costly (money-wise) to be a delegate and bake tezos?

Comment: It looks to me like you must transfer a positive amount to the delegate: https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/225364d9ad201b566e2f15d47f04078e220493f0/src/proto_003_PsddFKi3/lib_protocol/src/contract_storage.ml#L497 https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/225364d9ad201b566e2f15d47f04078e220493f0/src/proto_003_PsddFKi3/lib_protocol/src/contract_storage.ml#L478

Comment: Ah that's not the intended behavior then, should be fixed.